# SQL Query Remove Part of Path/Null

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I am new the whole SQL Query business but I need some help with two issues. My goal is to have anything in the Column "EnvironmentName" that has the word "Database" in Column "NodeName" to be displayed in the query results. I did this with

```
  FROM [Backbone_ASPIDER].[dbo].[vw_CFGsvr_Con]
  WHERE NodeName = 'Database' 
  ORDER BY EnvironmentName asc
  WHERE NodePath
```

Results of Query:

[image]

I am able to get my query results but would like to remove the rows with **NULL**. I have tried to use "IS NOT NULL" but SQL Server Management Studio labeles this as "**incorrect syntax**."

What I have tried:

```
FROM [Backbone_ASPIDER].[dbo].[vw_CFGsvr_Con]
WHERE NodeName = 'Database' 
ORDER BY EnvironmentName asc IS NOT NULL
WHERE NodePath
```

**Thank you in advance!**

Comment: add the queries you tried for 1 and 2

Comment: You've tried `IS NOT NULL` and the rows still displayed?  Are you sure the fields contain a `NULL` not just the word "NULL"?   try `ISNULL(EnvironmentName, 'NULL') != 'NULL'`

Comment: It's not saying your syntax is invalid because of the "is not null", it's saying it because you have a where clause, followed by an order by, followed by another where clause. You can only have one where clause, and it must go before any order by. You can concatenate conditions using and/or operators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is pretty close..
1: You have to specify a specific column to not be null while using IS NOT NULL.
So modify your query to:

```
FROM [Backbone_ASPIDER].[dbo].[vw_CFGsvr_Con]
WHERE NodeName = 'Database' AND EnvironmentName IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY EnvironmentName asc
WHERE NodePath
```

2: Check out this article about trimming parts of strings from query results
http://basitaalishan.com/2014/02/23/removing-part-of-string-before-and-after-specific-character-using-transact-sql-string-functions/

Answer (score 1):

Where clause will come first and Then order by statement 
Like following way

```
Select * FROM [Backbone_ASPIDER].[dbo].[vw_CFGsvr_Con]
WHERE [Backbone_ASPIDER].[dbo].[vw_CFGsvr_Con].[NodeName] = 'Database' AND [Backbone_ASPIDER].[dbo].[vw_CFGsvr_Con].[EnvironmentName]  IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY [Backbone_ASPIDER].[dbo].[vw_CFGsvr_Con].[EnvironmentName] asc
```

Comment: Thank you @Kaushik Thanki but now I am getting an error when I try to run the program: See question for new code/results

Comment: USE like this way [Backbone_ASPIDER].[dbo].[vw_CFGsvr_Con].[ModuleName]

Comment: I am sure that helped for it is now saying incorrent "."

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I just noticed you removed this from your OP, so feel free to disregard if you took care of that.

I don't think anyone addressed the substring problem yet. There's several ways you could get at this depending on how complex the strings are you have to slice up, but here's how I'd do it

```
-- Populating some fake data, representative of what you've got
if object_id('tempdb.dbo.#t') is not null drop table #t
create table #t
(
    nPath varchar(1000)
)

insert into #t
select '/Database/Mappings/Silver/Birthday' union all
select '/Database/Connections/Blue/Happy'


-- First, get the character index of the first '/' after as many characters the word '/database/' takes up.
-- You could have hard coded this value too. Add 1 to it so that it moves PAST the slash.
;with a as
(
    select 
        ixs = charindex('/', nPath, len('/Database/') + 1),
        -- Get everything to the right of what you just determined with all the charindex() stuff
        ss = right(nPath, len(nPath) -  charindex('/', nPath, len('/Database/') + 1)),
        nPath
    from #t
)
-- Now just take the left of the now-cleaned-up string from start to the first pipe
select
    ixs,
    ss,
    color = left(ss, charindex('/', ss) -1),
    nPath
from a
```